# Arch linux ca-certificates.crt not found

Tags: arch-linux, git, curl, certificates

I have a problem with the certificates in Arch linux. It seems that it can't find `ca-certificates.crt`. I have updated my system and installed the `ca-certificates{,-utils,-mozilla}` packages and it still doesn't work.

```
git clone http://github.com/sstephenson/bats.git
Cloning into 'bats'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sstephenson/bats.git/':     error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am posting an answer to my own question because I solved the problem and I did not find a valid solution elsewhere. There is no /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificate-crt file. So a link needs to be provided to the proper cert.

```
$ ln -s /etc/ca-certificates/extracted/ca-bundle.trust.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Now I can curl and git clone through https.

Comment: `certbot` was broken for me after March 2017's [ca-certificates-utils 20170307-1](https://www.archlinux.org/news/ca-certificates-utils-20170307-1-upgrade-requires-manual-intervention/) "manual intervention" update fix. This fixed `certbot`.

Comment: Thank you! Once again the answer to a mythical problem is found in a lone  stackexchange Q&A. This sovled certbot error for me ```OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with attempts to `git clone` from AUR. As with pianomanfrazier, creating a symlink resolved the immediate issue. However, I found that docker was still unable to pull, throwing the error:

```
docker: Error while pulling image: [image name]
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

Removing the symlink and running `pacman -S ca-certificate-utils` appeared to fix the underlying problem. (Noting docker needed a `systemctl restart docker` for the fix to take effect.)